# Data driven contents of a material-expansionpanel

Tags: dart, material-design, angular-dart, angular-components

I need to display a list of objects of different types in a repeating list of MaterialExpansionPanels. When the user clicks on each panel to expand it, the contents depend on the type of object.

I don't really have any idea for how to proceed - would the deferredContent directive allow me to determine which component to display at runtime when the panel is expanded? How would I specify the contents of the panel from my component code?

An example of something similar would be helpful!

Comment: `deferred` won't help at all. You can do something like explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468. The beta.17 example should be pretty much the same in Dart.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing really specific to material expansion here, you need to the the same things you would do in any place where *ngFor is used. You have basically two options:

1. Use series of *ngIf / *ngSwitch and render whatever you need inside
2. Use [Dynamic Component](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/lib/src/components/dynamic_component/dynamic_component.dart). This usually requires creating some model class with types and DI bindings to pass parameters.